# WebStorm icon too small with high dpi display on windows

Tags: webstorm, highdpi

I followed [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi) and set IDE size in WebStorm settings. It's almost fine but the icons are TOO small(it's really hard to touch them). The icons did not change with the IDE font size setting. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no solutions for this issue. Please vote for [IDEA-117729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117729)